# How To Add An Icon From File To MahApps.Metro WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

MahApps.Metro's [documentation](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html) has an icon at the top left of their tool bar.  It's called a [Window Icon](http://mahapps.com/images/04_ExplainedStyledWindow.png), and I've been having trouble getting one working.

I have a file called image.ico and I've added it as a resource in VisualStudio 2013, by going to `Project -> myproject Properties... -> Resources Tab -> Add Existing File... -> Selecting image`

The file is now listed as a resource named 'image', with its persistence set to 'Linked at compile time'.

I've tried two different tactics to get this to work.  The first one, was setting `Icon` and `ShowIconOnTitleBar` options.

**Method1**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="myprogram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="MyProgram" Height="400" Width="800"
        BorderThickness="2"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
        SaveWindowPosition="True"
        Icon="{StaticResource image}"
        ShowIconOnTitleBar="True">
```

This gives me an error for the `Icon` option.  I believe I am either setting the Resource incorrectly, or Icon wants something else entirely.

The second method is to still have the `ShowIconOnTitleBar="True"`, but set everything else in an `IconTemplate`.

**Method2**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="myprogram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="MyProgram" Height="400" Width="800"
        BorderThickness="2"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
        SaveWindowPosition="True"
        ShowIconOnTitleBar="True">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.IconTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                 Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                 Margin="4"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                 RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource image}"></Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.IconTemplate>
```

This gives me the error 'The Resource "image" could not be resolved'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your XAML, simply make `Icon="your_icon_file_name.ico"`, where `your_icon_file_name.ico` is added as an existing item to your project.

Comment: When you say "added as an existing item to your project"  do you mean added under Resources?  If so, then when I have ```Icon="image.ico"``` it says "Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12\Common7\IDE\image.ico"

Comment: Right-click your project and **Add -> Existing Item...** and then select your ico file.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: It did work.  Set as answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your project, **Add -> Existing Item...** and then select the desired `ico` file.

In your XAML assign the `ico` file name to the `Icon` property as below:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Icon="mahapps.metro.logo2.ico"
    Background="LightGray"
    Title="My Demo MetroWindow With Icon" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]